# How to stop web app from automatically getting timed out after one minute when http.get is called?

Tags: angular, http, iis, httpclient, http-get

I have to call an API function that returns a specific value in the angular side. However this api service takes 2-3 minutes to return the result. When I try this at my local environment, It works fine and the web section waits untill the response from API is obtained. But when I deploy it in the IIS, the web side is automatically getting timed out after 1 minute. Has anyone faced a similar problem before? Is there anyway to make your function wait for 3 minutes at the web side?

the following is how I have called the api function from my TS file

`return this.http.get(Endpoints.EndpointName);`

Comment: Anything that takes that long shouldn't be a single request/response cycle. The convention is to return 202 Accepted with a Location header telling the client where to poll for progress updates.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should see Connection Time-out:

[image]

You can try to increase the timeout in IIS.

Comment: This time out in IIS has the value for 5 minutes. But I still have the problem.

Comment: Have you also enabled'HTTP Keep-Alive' ?